# SQL Server update with joins

Tags: sql

I am trying to update a `date` in a table, based off of a `MAX(date)` in another table.  To get the correct data to link up, I have to do 2 inner joins and 2 left outer joins.

I can select the correct data, it returns a Guid (PersonId) and the Date.

I have to use this information to update my original table.  I am having trouble getting this to work, I still getting syntax errors.

```
update tblqualityassignments as assign
inner join tblrequirementteams as team on assign.guidmemberid = team.guidmemberid
set assign.dtmQAPCLed = dtmTaken
from
(
   select reg.guidpersonid, max(certs.dtmTaken) as dtmTaken  from tblqualityassignments as assign
   inner join tblrequirementteams as team on assign.guidmemberid = team.guidmemberid
   inner join tblregisteredusercerts as reg on team.guidpersonid = reg.guidpersonid
   left outer join tblcerttaken as certs on certs.guidcertid = reg.guidcertid
   left outer join tblCodesCertType as types on types.intcerttypeid = certs.intcerttypeid
   where types.intcerttypeid = 1 
    and assign.guidmemberid = team.guidmemberid 
   group by reg.guidpersonid as data
)
where data.guidpersonid = team.guidpersonid
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using SQL Server for this, then this should work:

```
UPDATE A
SET A.dtmQAPCLed = dtmTaken
FROM tblqualityassignments AS A
INNER JOIN tblrequirementteams as T 
ON A.guidmemberid = T.guidmemberid
INNER JOIN (select reg.guidpersonid, max(certs.dtmTaken) as dtmTaken  
            from tblqualityassignments as assign
            inner join tblrequirementteams as team 
            on assign.guidmemberid = team.guidmemberid
            inner join tblregisteredusercerts as reg 
            on team.guidpersonid = reg.guidpersonid
            left outer join tblcerttaken as certs 
            on certs.guidcertid = reg.guidcertid
            left outer join tblCodesCertType as [types] 
            on [types].intcerttypeid = certs.intcerttypeid
            where [types].intcerttypeid = 1 
            and assign.guidmemberid = team.guidmemberid 
            group by reg.guidpersonid) data
ON T.guidpersonid = data.guidpersonid
```

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 17
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'.

Comment: Also, the where statement needs to have the guidperson id = data.guidpersonid, and A must inner join with tblrequirementteams to get that, how do I handle the join in the where statement?